# Can ResearchGate upload preprints from ArXiv without author's consent?

Tags: publications, arxiv, preprint

I recently uploaded a preprint on ArXiv (the journal I submitted the manuscript allows this) under CC BY-NC-ND. However, it can be found on ResearchGate (without my consent). While it can be removed from my profile, it still appears on ResearchGate. Can ResearchGate automatically upload papers from arXiv without the author's consent?

Comment: Interesting question. It seems that [ResearchGate believes that they can](https://explore.researchgate.net/display/support/How+to+make+content+private+or+remove+it): "Why can't I remove a publication page or full-text? ... We sometimes make a full-text available where a publication has a Creative Commons license. If you feel that a publication has been wrongly attributed a Creative Commons license, please contact us at www.researchgate.net/contact."

Comment: Note that licenses are "sticky". Once you issue a license and someone takes advantage of it, you can't say oops and withdraw it (for them, at least).

Answer (score 7):

[Yes, anyone can share your work as long as they follow these restrictions.](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/)

That is the nature of an open license. You have already explicitly consented to let them do that.

The actual licence clause that matters here:

> For purposes of this Public License, the exchange of the Licensed Material for other material subject to Copyright and Similar Rights by digital file-sharing or similar means is NonCommercial provided there is no payment of monetary compensation in connection with the exchange.

To answer the (very relevant) question that got buried in the comments:

> If I want the preprint to appear only on arXiv and restrict platforms like ResearchGate distributing it, what license can I use?

There is a licence that you can choose which leaves you with full control over the use and copyright: [arXiv.org perpetual, non-exclusive license](https://arxiv.org/help/license). There is no legal right for anyone to rehost a manuscript that you give to arXiv under these terms. The only thing it allows is arXiv (and nobody else) to host your manuscript. Nobody else can use or reshare it for any (non-fair use) reason.

Comment: Seems like it hinges on whether this violates the "non commercial" clause in the license. I don't think that's a straightforward legal determination to make.

Comment: It doesn't unless they're selling it. It is straightforward.

Comment: That's one interpretation of non-commercial. It's not the only one, and is not consistent with the CC survey of what commercial use means to the content creators and users of content they surveyed https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Defining_Noncommercial

Comment: I don't think it is that straightforward, since ResearchGate is a commercial entity and benefits from having papers on its platform. See for example: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/1246/

Comment: There's an explicit carve out in the license for sharing files if there's no direct payment. It could not be clearer.

Comment: ResearchGate is not doing digital file sharing for other content. That would be something like a Torrent archive - everyone shares and distributes content, but no one makes any money off it. The only benefit the user gets is accessing others content. ResearchGate is a commercial website that is posting content for their financial gain - their business is being an attractive place for people to go for that content, they benefit financially from people visiting to view that content.

Comment: Also, your excerpt is from version 4 of the license, while your link points to version 2. Perhaps it should be updated? https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/

Comment: I submitted the manuscript to Elsevier. According to Elsevier policy, https://www.elsevier.com/about/policies/sharing authors can share their preprint anywhere at any time. The accepted manuscript can be shared immediately by updating a preprint in arXiv and after the embargo period, via non-commercial hosting platforms such as institutional repository. Accepted manuscripts should bear a CC-BY-NC-ND license. Does this mean that when I update the preprint on arXiv with the accepted version, ResearchGate has permission to upload it immediately? Doesn't the embargo period apply to ReseachGate?

Comment: @GoodDeeds Good catch, that was my mistake. And yes, once you release it under a CC license you lose a lot of the control you have over who can share it and how.

Comment: @BryanKrause I get the argument you're making, and I understand why rehosted files don't exactly feel kosher. My understanding is CC 5.0 might address that. As written and as enforced right now, a social media site can do what they're doing (although monetizing something like a youtube video that's CC-BY NC is different). The NC clause is why I think CC is a bad idea for software compared to a more explicit license like MIT or GPL.

Comment: @Libor ResearchGate has been sued by Elsevier over this very issue (well, a broader issue of distributing work that Elsevier feels they shouldn't, but -NC-ND works were part of the suit). I don't have a strong feeling on what the answer *should* be for the license, but it seems it's up to courts to decide and I doubt every court will come to the same conclusion, and I don't think it's a proper answer to say "yes they can do this". They think they can do this; others disagree.

Comment: @BryanKrause I didn't think a single CC-BY NC manuscript ended up in Elsevier's lawsuit although I could of course be wrong about that. There is already [case law](https://fairuse.stanford.edu/case/great-minds-v-fedex-office-print-services-inc/) that  supports reproducing CC-BY NC work, and I stand by the "yes they can do this", because the alternative (anyone can sue anyone and therefore the legal status of things is unknowable until a lawsuit) is unreasonable.

Comment: @Libor I'm not familiar with the particulars of the Elsevier lawsuit(s), I'm going just on others commentary like this blog: https://blogs.library.duke.edu/scholcomm/2018/11/08/acs-v-researchgate-3143-articles-and-a-few-lessons-about-their-authors/ which specifically mentions some CC-BY-NC-ND licensed papers were involved. Of course they could be misinformed in which case I am as well.

Comment: (...cont) I'm certainly no expert on legal matters but that case law you link to seems pretty irrelevant to this - in that case FedEx is only making money on the service they provide (which is independent of the license: they'd make the same fee regardless of the content). In the case of ResearchGate, they're getting ad revenue and such by being a host of the content, which makes their role overlap a lot with the rights that a publisher retains: effectively, the publisher's business model is in gating access to the content for fee or advertising. RG's commercial use is not much different.

Comment: It doesn't seem like RG could take a bunch of -NC papers, put them into a bound volume, and distribute it "free" while selling advertising in the intervening spaces. The legal question seems to be whether their website is effectively doing that, or if it's doing something different that is permissible. RG might have a better case if the authors themselves upload the papers, but OP isn't talking about that circumstance.

Comment: @BryanKrause I mean you should probably write that up as an answer if that's what you think. Who uploaded it isn't actually important in this case - because the authors released it under a CC license anyone (including researchgate) are free to use it as long as they don't change the license (which they are not). The only special power the authors have is to relicense it and release it under different terms. If the license doesn't apply to what they're doing it doesn't apply no matter who provided it.

Comment: @Libor If I want the preprint to appear only on arXiv and restrict platforms like ResearchGate distributing it, what license can I use? I thought CC BY-NC-ND is the most restricted license and arXiv mandates choosing a license when uploading the preprint. These are the available licenses in arXiv: https://arxiv.org/help/license

Comment: @DushiFdz `arXiv.org perpetual, non-exclusive license`: This says "Arxiv can have this but nobody else can", and you could release it under other licenses (or give away the copyright or bury it in your backyard forever). This would not allow a third party like ResearchGate to host your work. The CC BY-NC-ND is the most restrictive of the licenses that **explicitly allow anyone to use your work in almost any way they choose**

Comment: Thank you so much. The license chosen during arXiv submission is irrevocable and cannot be changed, but different versions of the same work can have different licenses. I think I should use arXiv.org perpetual, non-exclusive license when uploading the accepted version, but I am confused about this statement in Elseveir: "Accepted manuscripts should bear a CC-BY-NC-ND license" and then it mentions about an embargo period for non-commericla hosting.

Comment: @DushiFdz Elsevier doesn't **require** you to license your work under CC-BY-NC-ND. If you don't upload your work to a repository, you can license it using the [standard elsevier open license](https://www.elsevier.com/about/policies/open-access-licenses/elsevier-user-license) which would prohibit ResearchGate from rehosting it. ***IF*** you choose to upload your final elsevier manuscript to something like arXiv, they insist you license it under CC-BY-NC-ND (you don't have to do that for the preprint manuscript, you can do whatever you want with that, including a non-permissive license).